# A question about monotonic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Are only strictly increasing/decreasing sequences monotonic or can non-decreasing/increasing sequences also be called monotonic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a sequence monotonic increasing when $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$ holds and strictly monotonic increasing when $a_{n+1}> a_n$ holds. Therefore the case monotonic increasing includes the case strictly monotonic increasing.

See also the related: [Difference between Increasing and Monotone increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746077/505767)