# Is the term *monotone* used fairly consistently to mean non-decreasing or non-increasing but not strictly?

Tags: terminology, math-history, convention

In [BBFSK](https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke), (~1960, Germany) at least in the section I am currently reading, the authors use the term *monotone increasing (decreasing)* to mean what I often see called *strictly increasing (decreasing)*.  I'm not sure where I first learned to use the term *monotone* in the mathematical sense, but I believe it was first introduced to me as having the same meaning as *strictly monotone*.  That is, a monotone function is nowhere constant.  In contrast a function which is everywhere increasing or constant is called non-decreasing.

Checking an edition of Anton's very respectable Calculus book shows he uses the term to mean non-increasing(decreasing).  For me, that renders the term monotone virtually useless.

So I am wondering how much consistency there is in the field of mathematics regarding the definition of *monotone*.  Has this changed over the years, or does it vary from one language to another?

After posting, I checked my own list of definitions and found that I have it recorded that *monotone* means that the derivative never changes sign.  *Strictly monotone* means that the derivative is either everywhere positive, or everywhere negative.  *Monotone increasing (decreasing)* means the derivative is *everywhere positive (negative)*. So *monotone increasing (decreasing)* means strictly monotone.

Since I wrote that over a decade ago, I don't recall what my source was for that.

I also not that *monotone* often occurs in discussions of functions which do not have derivatives.  Such as natural number addition.

Comment: More appropriate for [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) cite.

Comment: Re your records: Note that strictly monotone does not even imply that the derivative exists. Also, $x\mapsto x^3$ is strictly monotone, but the derivative has a zero.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed.  I forgot to mention that.  I have now added a statement to my question acknowledging that *monotone* is also used to describe functions which do not have derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a very quick research that I did, I found that most people use *monotonically increasing* for what you would call *non-decreasing* (and vice-versa).

See for instance

- [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/monotone_function)

  - [Encyclopedia of maths](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Monotone_function)
  - [Another Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746077/difference-between-increasing-and-monotone-increasing-function)

However, it might be worth to explicitly mention if one is referring to the strict or non-strict variant since there seem to be also some texts that use the term *increasing* for *strictly increasing*.

Comment: Ha! See my updated question.  Apparently my notes agree with the last form you mentioned.

Comment: I don't mind providing my own definition of how a term is to be understood in context, if there is inconsistency between authors.  I prefer not to redefine a term that has a widely accepted meaning.  The phrase *strictly monotone increasing* has a superfluous adjective.